# Retrieve list of PCs that are not running a specific process

Tags: powershell

How do I get a list of PCs that don't have a process running with this script that I wrote?

```
<#
Searches AD for all computers that can ping and checks to see if a process 
is running 
#>

Import-Module active*

$PingTest = $null
$Clist = @()

Get-ADComputer -Filter *  -Properties * | ? {$_.operatingsystem -like  "*windows 7*"} |
    ForEach-Object {

        # test to see if the computer is on the network
        $PingTest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.name -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet 

        # If test is $true adds each computer to the array $Clist
        If ($PingTest) {$Clist += $_.name}
        Else {}

}#ForEach

#check for process running on each computer in the array $Clist

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Clist -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name mcshield}
```

Comment: Just a side-note, if you're going for terse, you can also use ForEach-Object's alias: `%` alongside Where-Object's `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-Process` inside an `If` statement. If a process is returned it will evaluate to true. You could then export the list out as a spreadsheet using `Export-Csv`

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -like '*Windows 7*'"
$ProcessRunning =  $Computers | 
    ForEach-Object {
        If ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.name -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet ) {
            If (Get-Process -ComputerName $_.name -Name mcshield -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    'ComputerName' = $_.name
                    'Process Running' = $True
                }
            } Else {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    'ComputerName' = $_.name
                    'Process Running' = $False
                }
            }
        }
    }

$ProcessRunning | Export-Csv C:\example\path.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and tell you if it works

Comment: cool I did not know about pscustomobject...very nice to learn that.

Comment: @WrightRobert The best way to acknowledge a good answer is to vote up and/or check mark as answer. See [why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: I am getting this error "Get-ADComputer : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running." If I run the get-AdComputer line by itself it works fine. Any Ideas.

Comment: I found the answer to the error https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx

Comment: This was my final solution that works!!   Thanks BenH!                                                    $GClist = Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like '*Windows 7*'" 
    ForEach ($Clist in $GClist) {
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $clist.name -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet ) {
            If (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $clist.name {Get-Process -Name mcshield } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {     
             Write-Host -ForegroundColor green $clist.name
            } Else {
             Write-Host -ForegroundColor red $clist.name
            }
        }}

Comment: btw how do you post a solution getting past the char boundry?

Comment: @WrightRobert What you posted would be an Answer rather than a comment. I updated my answer to place the output in a variable to get around the pipeline issue.

Comment: Thanks BenH! I'll post my final script when it's done